# Insert data in laravel IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: laravel, sqlsrv

So i got the problem when i insert the data on database sqlserver. the id sqlserver refuse to insert because the database want to insert id it self.

i have to try to set IDENTITY_INSERT ON like this :

`DB::statement('SET IDENTITY_INSERT articles ON;');`

and set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF like this :

`DB::statement('SET IDENTITY_INSERT articles OFF;');`

but it isn't work for my code.

```
   public function store(Request $request){
        //to sparate to methode
        $article = $request->isMethod('put') ? Article::findOrFail($request->article_id) : new Article;

        $article->id = $request->input('article_id');
        $article->title = $request->input('title');
        $article->body = $request->input('body');

        DB::statement('SET IDENTITY_INSERT articles ON;');
        if($article->save()){
            return new ArticleResources($article);
        }
        DB::statement('SET IDENTITY_INSERT articles OFF;');

    }
```

this error look like this:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'articles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `DB::unprepared()` instead of `DB::statement()`.

The difference is that `statement()` executes a prepared statement, while `unprepared()` uses `PDO::exec()` instead.

Every prepared statement starts a new session (inside the same database connection) and because the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` query is session-specific, it doesn't affect other prepared statements like the INSERT query.

`PDO::exec()` affects the whole database connection.

Like:

```
DB::unprepared('SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_table ON');
DB::table('articles')->insert(['id' => $request->input('article_id'), 'title' => $request->input('title'), 'body'=> $request->input('body')]);
DB::unprepared('SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_table OFF');
```

Comment: @Brian let me know if it helps.

Comment: Works 100%. Thank you

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27778) laravel issue for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an Assertion Error, try this workaround:

```sql
DB::unprepared('SELECT 1; SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_table ON');
DB::table('articles')->insert(['id' => $request->input('article_id'), 'title' => $request->input('title'), 'body'=> $request->input('body')]);
DB::unprepared('SELECT 1; SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_table OFF');
```

As Vikash Pathak mentioned, `DB::unprepared` will work, although in my case I was running into an issue running this on macOS when I had the Doctrine DBAL (Database Abstraction Layer) installed, which is a dependency of Laravel Nova. It turns out that `DB::unprepared` would return `false` for this statement, which worked fine except that the DBAL would cause an Assertion Error.

```
 AssertionError 

  assert($result !== false)

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:54
```

I struggled with a number of approaches to work around this but ultimately what I found was that by adding a trivial SELECT before the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON`, it would return `true` and the AssertionError would no longer be a problem.

Please let me know if there's a more elegant solution. It's possible that my particular issue was a driver quirk or DB setting, but I'm using the same Docker SQL Server 2019 configuration as on other environments that didn't have this issue.